# All records updated with same value when updating database Record

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I updated sql data base using c# text box but all records updated with same value what I entered in that text box. where I did wrong.

Below My code

```
private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = (@"Data Source = M2\SQL2016; Initial Catalog = inventoryDB; Integrated Security = True");

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd =
                    new SqlCommand("UPDATE companyDB SET compname=@label3", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@label3", cmpname.Text);
                int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not Updated");
    }
```

Comment: just add where clause in your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the where clause here to filter what records should be updated. The [WHERE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause is used to extract only those records that fulfill a specified criterion. See the following example which filters based on id column:

```
new SqlCommand("UPDATE companyDB SET compname=@label3 where id = @id", conn))
```

And:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id.Text);
```

Although specify the type directly and use the `Value` property is more better than `AddWithValue`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@label3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmpname.Text;
```

Also check here:
[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)